# Ошибка 0xc000007b (STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT) при запуске программы

Tags: windows

Пробовал устанавливать все рекомендованные софтины, в том числе и фиксящую, но это не дало никакого эффекта. Проверил отсутствие .dll через Dependency Walker (характерно для этой ошибки), и тут-то началось самое интересное:

[image]

Нашел массу .dll, которые по разрядности с моей системой не дружат и, собственно говоря, не позволяют запустить нужную мне программу.

Как избавиться от подобной ситуации?

Comment: Снести все фиксящие софтины и подробно рассказать что происходит у вас. Без подробностей - гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Какая разрядность запускаемой программы? Каковы разрядность, название и версия операционной системы? Внесите это дополнением в вопрос.